# Aptana Studio 3: Keyboard Shortcuts for Compare?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, compare, aptana

Is there any way to assign keyboard shortcuts for compare functions? I want to be able to click a key to select the next difference, another to replace from left to right, and another to replace from left to right. This seems so basic, but I can't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window/Preferences/General/Editors/Keys

filter using the word "compare", see if that is what you are looking for